# How to split object into groups by matching key value similarity in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I am building an Angular application.
I have to split my object into different objects by it's URI value, to later use in Expanding checkboxes solution (Being able to select All from the group, or specific ones).
I am currently dealing with the splitting of the objects into groups.

[StackBlitz data example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkdnib?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

What is the most efficient way to put them in arrays accordingly to the uri part going after `'/v2/'`?

Comment: Just use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter), the condition can be some like `item.uri.split("/")[2]=='information'` or you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get an array of object {name:..,items:..an array with the value } and then each array is the property items of the element you [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Find) with name the uri.split("/")[2]

Comment: Could you add the expected result for the example that you provide in the stackblitz in order to allow us to provide you a better filtering implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are two posible solutions that you could follow. The first one iterates over the array only once so I think could be the best way to go:

```
this.items.forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.uri.startsWith('/v2/information/')) {
    this.groupInformation.push(elem);
  } else if (elem.uri.startsWith('/v2/payments/')) {
    this.groupPayments.push(elem);
  } else if (elem.uri.startsWith('/v2/menu/')) {
    this.groupMenu.push(elem);
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
});
```

Here is another alternative:

```
this.groupInformation = this.items.filter((elem) =>
  elem.uri.startsWith('/v2/information/')
);
this.groupPayments = this.items.filter((elem) =>
  elem.uri.startsWith('/v2/payments/')
);
this.groupMenu = this.items.filter((elem) =>
  elem.uri.startsWith('/v2/menu/')
);
```

You could check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-okyypy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)